# Convert Prisma model to GraphQL model automatically

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, graphql-codegen

Given Prisma schema:

```
model companiesOnUsers {
  company   company      @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  companyId Int
  user      user         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
  role      companyRoles @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  roleId    Int
  createdAt DateTime     @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime     @updatedAt

  @@id([companyId, userId])
}
```

The question is, how do you generate GraphQL out of it? Writing this twice is not an option.

Comment: Did you have a look at Pothos Prisma Plugin? This should help you in creating GraphQL models based on your schema file https://github.com/hayes/pothos/tree/main/packages/plugin-prisma

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer: [TypeGraphQL Prisma package](https://prisma.typegraphql.com/docs/basics/usage)

Works with Prisma 4.8.0